# Parsing Wikipedia / Wikidata: how to get the current country based on city?

Tags: parsing, wikipedia, wikidata

I'm parsing wikidata/wikipedia and i'm currently writing a function like `get_country_by_city( $wikidata_id )`.
The problem: when eg. passing Q64 (Berlin), i'm getting 10 country instances and i want to get only the current country - which would be Q183.
is there maybe unique attribute for it?

Comment: Does [`&rank=preferred`](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=wbgetclaims&format=json&entity=Q64&property=P17&rank=preferred&formatversion=2) work for you?